# How can I specify which positional argument to use in tox?

Tags: python, tox

I have the following tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist = py37-{lint, test}

[testenv:py37-{lint, test}]
envdir = {toxworkdir}/lint_and_test_env
deps = 
    pylint
    pytest
    pytest-xdist
commands =
    lint: pylint src {posargs}
    test: pytest tests {posargs}
```

I want to run both environments in parallel and specify `--jobs=4` for pylint and `-n auto` for pytest. Executing `tox -p -- --jobs=4 -n auto` fails because pylint does not recognize the -n argument and vice versa.

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't think there is a way. `{posargs}` is just one string. You can try to parse it yourself inside `tox.ini`. But it'd simpler to write `lint: pylint src --jobs=4` and `test: pytest tests -n auto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no way to do what you want.

That said, I would strongly recommend that you split your environments and use one for testing and one for linting.

```
[tox]
envlist = py37, lint

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-xdist
commands =
    pytest tests {posargs}

[testenv:lint]
deps = pylint
commands = pylint src {posargs}
```

Then you can pass in different arguments to the commands, or run all envs via `tox`.

Also you could set defaults in case you do not specify `{posargs}`.

e.g.

```
[testenv:lint]
deps = pylint
commands = pylint src {--jobs=4:posargs}
```

If you want to run all `tox` envs in parallel you could run...

```
tox -p
```

P.S.: I am one of the `tox` maintainers, and I have contributed to hundreds of open source projects, and basically 99% use separate envs for testing and linting.

P.P.S.: If you want to run more than one linter, you should have a look at [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/).

Comment: is it okay to run "poetry run pre-commit run -a -v" from within a tox.ini file? or should I do it the long way by having multiple commands to do "poetry run flake8 . \npoetry run black .\npoetry run isort ...." What I am saying is that manually invoking pre-commit inside tox file acceptable?

Comment: I have no experience with poetry, but I always run pre-commit via tox, see eg https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/31055e625e1be0a1b7bcaadc1d0c81381a26afe1/tox.ini#L24

Comment: why do you have separate commands in your tox.ini like  mypy --strict src tests {posargs} when you could run mypy from pre-commit as well

Comment: When developing I like to run them separate. Though I could do this also with something like `tox -e pre-commit -- run mypy`. Additionally, most linters are static, so you do not need to install the package, whereas for mypy you need to install the package - though in the above linked file I did not take this into account. Installing takes time.

Comment: I did eventually end up splitting linting and testing into different environments and like it better than the previous solution. The downside is that the CI pipeline now has to create two virtual environments.